# MySQL Table does not exist, but it does

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I am new to building databases, i have created a database for a website i am creating, and i keep getting this message "Executing SQL script in server
ERROR: Error 1146: Table 'mydb.franch' doesn't exist", when trying to forward engineer my database. The table does exist but it is not being read. (See image below). Please any help will be appreciated.

[image: Error message]
[image: Table exists]

Comment: Are you shure your db name is correct on website?

Comment: Have your changes to the database been committed?

Comment: I haven't connected the db to the website yet, i am still trying to forward engineer the db so i can connect my website to it darth. blong i am not sure what you mean

Answer (score 0):

I can't add a comment, but in your image the table is "Franch" not "franch". Maybe that is the problem?

Comment: Thank you i will try that now

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong but I believe you are trying to access your table as (something like)

```
select * from 'mydb.franch'
```

or

```
select * from `mydb.franch`
```

In either case it's wrong and should be

```
select * from `mydb`.`franch`
```

Comment: Thank you. but the images shown are of the db forward engineering not a query

Answer (score 0):

MYSQL is case sensitive when creating a table, which means that you cannot create a table or variable with lower/upper case, and call it with upper/lower cases.

As such you must call the same name you used to create the table. In this case since the table is called **`mydb`.`Franch`** you would do: `select * from`mydb`.`Franch;`

Comment: Hi, above is not a query, it is literally the program trying to forward engineer the db, the software is doing this all by itself